# The number of schools is not enough / sufficient / adequate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I wanted to say

> The number of schools in the country is not enough. The government should build more schools to meet the demand and raise the quality of education.

by using the words *sufficient* or *adequate*. However, I couldn't reach any results with these words after Google search. I think these words are used to refer to the capacity of a specific school but not used to refer to the number of schools. Which words can I use to imply the meaning in my sentence instead of not enough.

Comment: But why doesn't "not enough" not work? It seems fine to me.

Comment: The only thing awkward about this sentence is that "The number of schools" is the subject. It would be better to say "There are not enough schools in the country".

Comment: You could stick with "number of schools" if you use "is too small", but "There are not enough schools" seems like a good solution.

Comment: @AIQ The more words the merrier. I also feel like "not enough" does not convey a sense of desperation

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think it is also good to say " there are not sufficient schools"

Comment: First, for simplicity, use their opposite words rather than fitting the positive words into a negative construction with the positive words. (1) *The number of schools in the country is (**insufficient** | **inadequate**).* You can also rephrase the sentence further to make it even more natural. (2) *This country has an (**insufficient** | **inadequate**) number of schools.* But there's nothing wrong with any of these versions—nor with the original version.